# Is ng2-file-upload angular 4 compatible?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ng-file-upload for my angular 4 project.It doesn't works as I was unable to browse any files if i use the directive.However the modal for browsing files is rendered if there is no attribute for ng2-file-upload.Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its compatible in angular 4 too. This might help -
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/742